# Rswag nested attributes syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, swagger, rswag

i have a project in which i have to write nested attribute in rswag

```
{
  "question_bank": {
    "question_exams_attributes": {
      "0": {
        "question_bank_id": "",
        "exam_id": "12",
        "sub_category_id": "23",
        "_destroy": "false"
      }
    },
    "question_type": "Single best answer",
    "difficulty": "easy",
    "status": "active",
    "tag_list": [
      ""
    ],
    "question": "testing api 2"
  },
  "commit": "Submit"
}
```

i am trying to write this json body in nested attribute syntax in rswag:
i have tried this:

```
 parameter name: :question_bank, in: :body, schema: {
        type: :object,
        properties: {
          question_exams_attributes: {
            type: :object,
            properties: {
              '0': {
              properties: {
                question_bank_id: { type: :string },
                exam_id: { type: :string },
                sub_category_id: { type: :string }
                }
              }
            }    
          }    
        }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue too.

Here is how I solved it.

```rb
schema type: :object,
            properties: {
              title: { type: :string },
              content: { type: :string },
              comments: {
                type: :array,
                items: {
                  type: :object,
                  properties: {
                    content: { type: :string }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
```

In your case I think you're missing the type on the "0" element.

```rb
properties: {
          question_exams_attributes: {
            type: :object,
            properties: {
              '0': {
              type: :object,
              properties: {
                question_bank_id: { type: :string },
                exam_id: { type: :string },
                sub_category_id: { type: :string }
                }
              }
            }    
          }    
        }
```